# Default value of DropDownList in an Html.BeginForm block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

While a search of "Default value of *DropDownList*" produces results, this is not a duplicate question because the specific issue is not listed in the examples and answers I have searched.

Here is the main question first, followed by supporting background and details:

**When I place a  DropdownList in an Html.BeginForm block, how can I have the default DropDownList values be an item *other* than the first item in the list?**

**What I have done so far:**

- SO, Microsoft Virtual Academy, and a general Internet Search using various search terms, with no *effective* answers that solve this specific issue.
- Looking at the overloads of `Html.DropDownList` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx). The `optionLabel` parameter inserts an item at the very top of the list, such as "Select an Item", which is not desired behavior.
- jQuery, which *does* work as intended, but I'm really hoping there is a much *simpler* way that doesn't involve jQuery.

***My Working Theory:*** The method I learned (and shown below) does not allow for default values and it is not a case of not knowing a particular overload of `Html.DropDownList`.

**Background Info:**

In the process of learning MVC 5 and gathering instructions from tutorials and SO answers, I learned this style of creating a DropDownList that is placed within a `Html.BeginForm()` block in the View. It works, if I want the default value to be the first item in the list or if I want to add an item inserted at the top that says "select an item."

However, there are times when it is meaningful to for the default value to be other than the first in the list.

In the controller, the defaults of the parameter are set `Index(string campus = "MRA", string fy = "FY16")`, and the query returns the correct result, but DropDownLists are not set accordingly when loading the page for the very first time.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string campus = "MRA", string fy = "FY16")
{
    /* The ViewBags feed DropDownLists used to filter the query */
    ViewBag.CampusList = new List<string> { "CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA"};
    ViewBag.FyList = new List<string> {"FY15","FY16" };

    IEnumerable<AssociatedW3SuspensionOrProbation> query = 
            db.AssociatedW3SuspensionOrProbation
            .Where(m=>m.Campus==campus).Where(m=>m.FY==fy)
            .OrderBy(m=>m.StudentName).ThenBy(m=>m.LatestEntryDate);

    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

**View**
The dropdowns function correctly: when the form is submitted, the query results are chosen by the selected dropdown values and the dropdowns load with the selected values.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                <strong>Campus</strong>: @Html.DropDownList("campus",
                    new SelectList(ViewBag.CampusList)) ||

                <strong>FY</strong>: @Html.DropDownList("fy", 
                    new SelectList(ViewBag.FyList))
            </p>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Is there a simple answer to this problem, or does this require a totally different approach?

Comment: Have you tried the overload of `new SelectList()` which takes the selected value as the second parameter?  `new SelectList(ViewBag.CampusList, "MRA")`

Comment: Why the downvote? Was the question poorly constructed? Did I fail to sufficiently explain the question? I'm open to criticism, but simply getting a downvote without any explanation is not constructive or helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is create `SelectList` in the controller action and there is a constructor overload which can be used to set selected value, but for that you would need a `List<T>` which is not string but a custom type that contains 2 properties 1 for TextField and 1 for ValueField.

You have to use [second Constructor overload listed here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.)

Here is the example code:

```
ViewBag.CampusList = new SelectList(
                                    new List<string> { "CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA"},
                                    campus  // selected value 
                                   );
    ViewBag.FyList = new SelectList(
                                    new List<string> {"FY15","FY16" },
                                    ,fy    // selected value
                                   );
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("campus",
                ViewBag.CampusList as SelectList)

@Html.DropDownList("fy", 
                ViewBag.FyList as SelectList)
```

Comment: Perfect. The modification I'd make to the answer is: `ViewBag.CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> { "CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA"}, "MRA");`

Comment: The Variable is used within your action to pass it, this code should be in your action,  I think you wrote above in view directly

Comment: No, I wrote the default value in the controller, where the ViewBag is defined.